# DocBlox Configuration: The given template default could not be found or is not readable

Tags: php, docblox

I have installed the latest 0.18.1 DocBlox on Ubuntu 11.10 using PEAR.  Everything seems to work fine if I specify everything on the command line. However, using the docblox alone will not find the docblox.xml in the current directory. Specifying the doxblox -c (or --config) ./docblox.xml does not work either.  I have verified permissions and that the file exists.

I have a directory Testing with some simple files for testing.

```
/home/Testing$ docblox --config ./docblox.xml    
DocBlox version 0.18.1    

ERROR: The given template default could not be found or is not readable    

/home/Testing$ ls -l    
total 20    
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dev      dev       992 2012-01-17  12:03  docblox.xml    
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dev      dev       107 2012-01-17  11:59  index.php    
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dev      dev       769 2012-01-17  12:01  SOME_CLASS.class    
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dev      dev      1335 2012-01-17  12:02  SOME_CLASS.class.test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default` template was until version 0.18.0 the de-facto template and has been renamed to `new_black` in version 0.18. Perhaps you directly mention the `default` template in your own configuration?

try to install the `new_black` template and either omit the template name in your configuration or define `new_black`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  After removing the template section, this corrected my problems and I can generate the reports and class graph.  The following is my new basic docblox.xml for anyone that might need it.

Answer (score 0):

You propably must install the theme. I had to do it myself in the first release after the maintainer separated the themes from the core

```
$ pear list-all -c docblox
All packages [Channel docblox]:
===============================
Package                                Latest Local
docblox/DocBlox                        0.18.1 0.18.1 PHP 5.3 compatible API Documentation generator aimed at projects of all sizes and Continuous Integration
docblox/DocBlox_Template_abstract      1.0.1         The abstract template for DocBlox
docblox/DocBlox_Template_checkstyle    1.0.0  1.0.0  The checkstyle template for DocBlox
docblox/DocBlox_Template_new_black     1.0.1  1.0.1  The new_black template for DocBlox
docblox/DocBlox_Template_old_ocean     1.0.0         The old_ocean template for DocBlox
docblox/DocBlox_Template_pdf_old_ocean 1.0.0         The pdf_old_ocean template for DocBlox
docblox/DocBlox_Template_zend          1.0.0         The zend template for DocBlox
docblox/DocBlox_Theme_default          1.0.0         The default theme for DocBlox

$ pear install docblox/DocBlox_Theme_default
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing the template section, this corrected my problems and I can generate the reports and class graph.  The new docblox.xml is below for anyone who needs it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<docblox>
   <title>My project</title>
   <parser>
       <target>output</target>
       <markers>
           <item>TODO</item>
           <item>FIXME</item>
       </markers>
       <extensions>
           <extension>class</extension>
           <extension>fn</extension>
           <extension>php</extension>
       </extensions>
       <visibility></visibility>
   </parser>
   <transformer>
       <target>output</target>
   </transformer>
   <logging>
       <level>warn</level>
       <paths>
           <default>{APP_ROOT}/data/log/{DATE}.log</default>
           <errors>{APP_ROOT}/data/log/{DATE}.errors.log</errors>
       </paths>
   </logging>
   <files>
       <file>*</file>
       <file>bin/*</file>
       <directory>src</directory>
       <directory>tes??</directory>
       <ignore>test/*</ignore>
   </files>
</docblox>
```